# Convergence of a sequence of RVs

Tags: probability-theory

**Question:**
A sequence of RVs $X_1,X_2 ... $ converges by distribution to a RV if $\forall x \in \Bbb R, i \in \Bbb N: P(X_i=x) \to P(X=x)$.
Prove that these series uniformly converge (so you need to prove: $\forall x\in \Bbb R \forall \varepsilon >0 \exists N \forall  n>N: |P(X_n=x)-P(X=x)| \le \varepsilon)$

**What I did:**
Since this is the first time I met this combination of calculus and probability, I tried proving it the same as I would a regular limit (Looking for an N that satisfies this). But I don't really know anything about these sequences apart from the fact:
$\sum_{\forall x \in \Bbb R}P(X_n=x)=1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{\forall x \in \Bbb R}P(X_n=x)=\infty$
So I don't know how I can find such an N

Thanks.

Comment: There's something very wrong with this question.  Firstly if the distribution of the $X_i$'s is continuous then $P(X_i = x)=0$, so any sequence of continuous random variables converges to any given continuous random variable.  If you replace the "$=$" signs inside the probabilities with "$\leq$" you get a definition of convergence that makes sense, but the statement you're trying to prove is the same statement as in the question. That's what the "$\to$" sign means.

Comment: I forgot to mention a detail about x (forall x). I hope this makes this question okay...

Comment: No it doesn't, is that the exact text of the question? I'm happy to help but can you check it very carefully.

Comment: Translated it really word by word now... Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Ok, I'll post an answer with a few reasons the question is wrong then you can decide what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long, long answer.

One of two things has happened, either whoever wrote the question has some serious holes in his understanding of probability theory, or more likely they wrote the question last thing on a Friday and weren't really paying attention.

Personally I'd just have skipped the question and not worried about it.

If you want to talk to the lecturer about it be very polite and say you don't understand the question and you think there might be a typo. Hopefully he didn't write the questions himself, but if he did you don't want to accuse him of not understanding the subject he's teaching. (That might be the case but he'll get defensive if you say it directly.)

The statement of the question is incorrect in at least three ways.

First the statement
$$\forall x\in\mathbb R, i\in \mathbb N:P(X_i = x)\to P(X = x)$$
is meaningless.  I'm assuming that this should read 
$$\forall x\in\mathbb R:P(X_i = x)\to P(X = x)\text{ as }i\to\infty.$$

a random variable with domain $\mathbb R$ is usually continuous.
A random variable is continuous if its probabililty distribution is given by its density function $f_X$ and you get statements like
$$P(a\leq X \leq b) = \int_a^b f_X(x). dx$$
But $\int_a^a f_X(x) dx = 0$ for every $a$ so we must have $P(X=a) = 0$ for every continuous random variable.

So if $X_n$ is *any* sequence of continuous random variables and $Y$ is *any other* continuous random variable then  $P(X_i = x) \to P(Y=x)$ for every $x$ because a sequence of zeros converges to zero.  You can't have a definition of convergence that says every sequence converges to every limit.

One definition of convergence in distribution is as follows.

A sequence of random variables $X_n$ *converges in distribution* to a *continuous* random variable $X$ if and only if
$$\forall x\in\mathbb R:P(X_i \leq x)\to P(X \leq x)\text{ as }i\to\infty.$$

(I've had to restrict the definition to continuous limits here to keep my corrections looking even vaguely like the question. This is not a very good definition of converges in distribution.)

If you remember your real analysis classes this statement is shorthand for
$$\forall x\in\mathbb R, \varepsilon >0 \exists N\in\mathbb N\text{ such that }\forall n>N: \left|P(X_i \leq X) - P(X_i \leq X)\right| <\varepsilon.$$

So if we replace $P(X_i = X)$ and  $P(X_i = X)$ with $P(X_i \leq X)$ and $P(X_i \leq X)$ in both the question and the answer then the question and the answer are the same.

The definition of a uniform convergence of functions is as follows
We say a sequence of functions $f_i:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ *converges uniformly* to a function $f$ if 
$$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb N\text{ such that } \forall x\in\mathbb R: \left|f_i(x) - f(x)\right|. $$

So for $f_i(x) =P(X_i\leq x)$ and $f(x) = P(X\leq X)$ the statement you should be trying to prove is
$$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb N\text{ such that } \forall x\in\mathbb R: \left|P(X_i\leq x) - P(X\leq x)\right|. $$

So the difference between the (corrected) statement in the question and the one you are trying to prove is that the $\forall x$ has been moved to the right of the "such that".

You can try to prove this yourself if you want, but I think it's much harder than the question was supposed to be. You don't need to know anything about the random variables themselves apart from the fact that $X$ is a continuous random variable. That means that for every $x\in\mathbb R$ we have $P(X=x)=0$.
Equivalently you can say that for every sequence $x_i$  of real numbers with $x_i\to x$ as $x\to\infty$ we have $P(X < x_i) \to P(X<x)$.

You need to use this fact in the proof, consider the following example of what can go wrong if I don't assume that $X$ is continuous.

Let $X_i$ be the random variable such that $X_i = 0$ with probability $0.5$ and $X_i = 1-\frac 1i$ with probability $0.5$.

So if $x<1$ then $P(X_i\leq x) = 0.5$ for sufficiently large $i$ and for $x\geq 1$; $P(X_i\leq x) = 1$ for every $i$.  So the definition above is satisfied by the random variable $X$ which is $0$ with probabiltiy $0.5$ and $1$ with probability $0.5$.

But for $\varepsilon = \frac 13$ I can set $x_i = 1-\frac1{i+1}$
and 
$$\left|P(X_i < x_i) - P(X < x_i)\right| = \frac 12 >\frac 13.$$

So for this value of $\varepsilon$ I can't choose an $N$ where $\left|P(X_n < x) - P(X < x)\right| <\varepsilon$ for every $x$ whenever $n>N$. Therefore the sequence doesn't converge uniformly.

If you were to try to prove the statement you should argue that if $P(X_i < x)$ converges for every $x$, but not uniformly then you must be able to choose a sequence $x_i$ and an $\varepsilon$ for which $\left|P(X_i < x_i) - P(X < x_i)\right| >\varepsilon$. From here you can choose a convergent subsequence of $x_i$ and use a diagonal argument to show that there must be some value of $x$ such that $P(X=x)\geq\varepsilon$. (Be careful though I'm allowing $x=\infty$.)

I don't recommend doing that, it's not something anyone would expect an undergraduate to be able to do on their own.

I don't think that's actually going to help you much in this situation, but I hope that it helps with something.